# Logical Drives degraded due to the loss of a redundant path. What is wrong?

Tags: hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, sas, hp-storageworks

HP p822 (four external minisas ports) to pair of d2700s Storage Enclosures.  Two ports on the p822 are unused.

The partitioning is not at all identical.  The top box has four different logical drives and the bottom box is one single drive for backups.

i have the minisas cables arranged in the following "Dual domain example — best fault tolerance cabling" pattern from page 48 of :[image]
[![HP StorageWorks
D2600/D2700 Disk Enclosure User Guide page ][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6OTA.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6OTA.jpg)

Upon bootup and initialization of the p822, i get an error that may implicate the path from Port 3E of the p822:

```
1738-Slot 2 Drive Array Storage Enclosure Redundant Cabling Problem Detected    
    Check storage box I/O module and cable to restore redundant paths to the following disk drive(s):    
    Port 3E: Box 1: Bays 1-25
    Port 3E: Box 2: Bays 1-25
```

But BIOS level ACU throws warnings that "* 799 Logical Drive X is degraded due to the loss of a redundant path*."
[image]

Comment: Check your cables and the controller. Or better yet, provide the full output (http://pastebin.com) of the `hpssacli` tool: `ctrl all show config` and `ctrl all show config detail`

Comment: If you've cabled it that way then presumably you have a dead cable, controller port or disk-shelf port as that's definitely a correct way to cable this - have you any more detail in ACU that would help you identify which path is down?

Comment: Wishing we had multicolored mini-sas cables so that server room photos were useful.  Once i get it booted into an OS and connected to the LAN, will run those utils.

Comment: The directions do say to pull power cords after switching off storage enclosures.  Wondering if that trouble is worth it.

Comment: @rjt Please post the the `hpssa` command line output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you check cabling? I experience problems with some mini-SAS cables. Sometimes, you must pull the blue trip/tab before you can correctly push the connector.

Comment: Yep, that was the problem back then, visually the cables looked plugged in all the way, but they were in fact not.